# How to add set elements to a string in python

Tags: python, string, set

how would I add set elements to a string in python? I tried:

```
sett = set(['1', '0'])
elements = ''
for i in sett:
       elements.join(i)
```

but no dice. when I print elements the string is empty. help

Comment: What result exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: When you say "join" you mean "string concatenate". "String concatenate set entries". (You could also have meant "set-join", "list-append", etc).

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want this:

```
s = set(['1', '2'])

asString = ''.join(s)
```

Be aware that sets are not ordered like lists are.  They'll be in the order added typically until something is removed, but the order could be different than the order you added them.

Answer (score 1):

## Strings are immutable.

`elements.join(i)` does not change `elements`. You need to assign the value returned by `join` to something:

```
s = set(['1', '0'])
elements = ''
for i in s:
    elements = elements.join(i)
```

But, as others pointed out, this is better still:

```
s = set(['1', '0'])
elements = ''
elements = elements.join(s)
```

or in its most concise form:

```
s = set(['1', '0'])
elements = ''.join(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sett = set(['1', '0'])
elements = ''
for i in sett:
    elements += i
# elements = '10'
```

However, if you're just looking to get a string representation of each element, you can simply do this:

```
elements = ''.join(sett)
# elements = '10'
```

Comment: In that case `''.join(sett)` is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @Achim: I was getting there. Just needed to triple-check the syntax. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ''.join(set(['1','2']))
'12'
```

I guess this is what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know what you mean with "add set elements" to a string. But anyway: Strings are immutable in Python, so you cannot add anything to them.

Comment: Technically correct. But without an example of the right way to do things, it's not very helpful for Wyatt.

Comment: Technically correct. ;-) But when I answered, the question was not formatted at all and I didn't got the idea what he wanted to do at all.